# Analysis of canvas rendering performance

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm developing a rendering of an isometric 3d environment made up of blocks (kind of minecraft).

I'm drawing it in a canvas using its 2d context (and doing some math).

On page load a loop is created adding some blocks each frame (`window.requestAnimationFrame(fn)`), but I'm struggling with low fps when rendering.

This is first time for me to go so deep in performance analysis, and I'm struggling understanding the performance view of Chrome Devtools.

Looking at the results:

[image: output]

What I understand is that the frame took 115.9ms to complete, but looking at the processes seems it took just ~30ms to do the calculation using the canvas API, but in the task bar (upon the *Animation Frame Fired*) I see much longer time for the frame to complete.

Is this a common behavior? Have I did some dumb mistake wasting performance some way?
(if it is a common behavior, what is happening during that time? Is it the actual drawing?)

I blocked as I'm wondering if I should try to improve my algorithm of drawing, or I should look somewhere else to address a bottleneck

Comment: Devtools doesn't show some activities by default so you need to enable them manually, https://puu.sh/FrDS5/8bc05c5844.png (it's [somewhat complicated](https://hackernoon.com/hidden-experimental-features-in-chrome-devtools-2ae93b11b628) in current Chrome but simple in Chrome Canary). You can also use chrome://tracing for more info or enable [paint instrumentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference#paint-profiler).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you ever got an answer to this, but one thing that jumps out at me is that in your screenshot the green "GPU" bar is nearly solid.  As I understand it, this bar indicates that the browser is sending instructions and/or data to the GPU for hardware-accelerated rendering.  In my experience this can be a problem if you're using a slow graphics card, depending on what you're trying to do.

The good news is that I would expect testing on a more powerful system to result in an immediate framerate improvement.  The bad news is, I'm not sure how to tell exactly which canvas operations put that much load on your (bad) GPU or how to optimize to reduce GPU traffic.